# BlackBerry Localization: Pick specific resource locale issue

Tags: blackberry, localization, internationalization, blackberry-jde

I need to know if it is possible to select a specific resource locale for my language.

Instead of changing my phone's language setting, can I in code make use of it depending upon some conditions?

Here's a piece of code I wrote: A user should be able to change language and see its effect inside the app itself.

```java
String appLocale = LanguageManager.getCurrentUserSelectedLanguage();

if (appLocale.equals("en" /*or "de" or "es" etc */)) {
    ResourceBundle _resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_ID, BUNDLE_NAME);
    localizedString = _resources.getString(key);
} ...

return localizedString;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve the issue! This is for all who are interested. Here's the code:

```
if(appLocale.equals("en")){
ResourceBundle _resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle(LocalizationResource.BUNDLE_ID, LocalizationResource.BUNDLE_NAME).getBundle(Locale.get(Locale.LOCALE_en));
localizedString = _resources.getString(key);
}
else if(appLocale.equals("es")){
ResourceBundle _resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle(LocalizationResource.BUNDLE_ID, LocalizationResource.BUNDLE_NAME).getBundle(Locale.get(Locale.LOCALE_es));
localizedString = _resources.getString(key);
}
```

I used only one resource file(.rrh) and simply picked up the language bundle using
`Locale.LOCALE_es` and `Locale.LOCALE_en`
 depending upon my app language I received from the user.